# Querying R to find default bitmap resolution of current R session

Tags: r, bitmap, default, resolution

Is there a way of interrogating my current R-session to confirm the default bitmap resolution?

A number of questions involving saving charts as bitmaps discuss how the resolution can be set to some desired resolution when the output is saved to a file.  e.g. bitmap(file,..., res=300,...), where in this case the resolution of the bitmap image saved to file would be 300dpi.

Several of the responses seem to state that the default bitmap resolution for R is 72dpi.

My question: is there a way I can interrogate my current R-session to see what its default resolution for bitmaps actually is?  Or do I just have to 'know' that 72dpi is the default.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple ways to see the default values for formal arguments of a function.

```
args(bitmap)
#function (file, type = "png16m", height = 7, width = 7, res = 72, 
#    units = "in", pointsize, taa = NA, gaa = NA, ...) 
#NULL

formals(bitmap)$res
#[1] 72
```